# taiwlind JavaScript can't get executed in blazor .net8 with @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css, flowbite

I recently configured a Blazor project with Auto rendering mode, incorporating Tailwind CSS. However, I encountered challenges when using components that require flowbite.min.js in Razor pages with the `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly` attribute. Disabling this attribute enables Tailwind to function correctly for these components but disrupts the execution of `@onclick` events. This dilemma forces a trade-off between optimal Tailwind performance and the proper functioning of Blazor events, depending on the presence or absence of `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly`.

This code utilizes flowbite.min.js:

```
<button data-drawer-target="drawer-example" data-drawer-show="drawer-example" aria-controls="drawer-example" type="button">
    New Appointment
</button>
<div id="drawer-example" aria-labelledby="drawer-label">
</div>
<button id="blazor" @onclick="SomeFun" />
```

When `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly` is not added, the code effectively displays the canvas off (drawer), but the button's (blazor) click event will not be triggered. Conversely, when @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly is present, the flowbite.min.js-dependent code fails to work, but the blazor button successfully handles the `@onclick` event.

Here is my App.razor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body class="p-5 bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 antialiased !p-0">
    <Routes />

    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
     <script src="js/flowbite.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/site.js"></script>
 
  
</body>

</html>
```

I also have to mention that in Microsoft documentation, they always show samples without setting the `@rendermode`.

Comment: Without any error messages or a minimum example, we cannot help much. I suspect it's not the js but how you're communicating with it and dealing with the switch from server to wasm. Also, the auto render modes include SSR first this can be disabled.

Comment: I have revised the entire post to provide a clearer explanation of my issue.

Comment: What errors do you see on the browser console?

Comment: Appreciation to @RBee for investigating this matter. I've recently shared a solution to my question for the benefit of others facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

For individuals encountering a similar issue, I have successfully identified the resolution through the following link: https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite/pull/739/files.

If you adhere to the Flowbite documentation, it may not yield the expected results. Please refer to https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/blazor/#install-flowbite for more information.